# \leadsto draws differently to what is expected

Tags: arrows

I have found in many sites that the `\leadsto` command produces this arrow:

[image]

However when I use it I get this

[image]

Why? How can I do to get the first one?

Here is the code producing the second version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[
  \leadsto
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

David's answer covers the reason why you get a “different” `\leadsto` symbol. However, loading `latexsym` changes can also affect other symbols as it should be done *after* `amssymb`.

[image]

As you see, also `\Join`, `\Box` and `\Diamond` change their shape.

For just the `\leadsto` symbol, you can define it alone:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareSymbolFont{lasy}{U}{lasy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{lasy}{bold}{U}{lasy}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol\leadsto{\mathrel}{lasy}{"3B}

\begin{document}
$\mho\Join\Box\Diamond\leadsto\sqsubset\sqsupset\lhd\unlhd\rhd\unrhd$       
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}

\begin{document}
\[
  \leadsto
\]
\end{document}
```