# How to write the arrow of the two overlap style?

Tags: arrows

I want to write the following arrow in latex. But I fail to search for an answer.

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: Please show us, what you try so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's some strange symbol...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\newcommand*{\negdblleadsto}{\leadsto\mkern-15mu\not\leadsto}

\begin{document}

$A \negdblleadsto B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `latexsym` is a relatively old package; however the more common `amssymb` version looks quite different. You might want to use `amssymb` but import the `latexsym` definition of `\leadsto` as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266480/82917).